# How to count number of records in a group and save them in a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset as below:

```
import  pandas as pd

dict = {"A":[1,1,1,1,5],"B":[1,1,2,4,1]}

dt = pd.DataFrame(data=dict)
```

so, it is as below:

```
  A  B
  1  1
  1  1
  1  2
  1  4
  5  1
```

**i need to apply a groupby based on `A` and `B` count how many records each group has?**

i have applied the below solution:

```
dtSize = dt.groupby(by=["A","B"], as_index=False).size()
dtSize.to_csv("./datasets/Final DT/dtSize.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

I have 2 problems:

1. When i open the saved file, it only contains the last column which includes number element in each group, but it does not include the **groups**
2. when i print the final `dtSize` it is as below:

[image]

so, some similar records in `A` is missed.

My favorit output is as below in a `.csv` file

```
A  B   Number of elements in group
1  1    2
1  2    1
1  4    1
5  1    1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, data from `A` isn't missing. [GroupBy.size](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) returns a Series, so `A` and `B` are used as a `MultiIndex`. Due to this, repeated values for `A` in the first three rows aren't printed.

You're close. You need to reset the index and, optionally, name the result:

```py
dt.groupby(['A', 'B']).size().reset_index(name='Size')
```

The result is:

```
   A  B  Size
0  1  1     2
1  1  2     1
2  1  4     1
3  5  1     1
```

Comment: could you please explain, how resetting index does this?

Comment: I edited the answer with the explanation. Just to give you a bit more information, resetting the index shifts the Index of the series into columns. If  you had a single index, only one column will be produced. Since you did a groupby, this created a MultiIndex of two levels, A and B. Therefore, resetting the index gives you two new columns. The `name` kwarg gives the original series values a column name.